# How to erase a string and what comes after in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

i'm trying to get rid of a few character within a string:

"V.I.E Responsable Projets Marque Propre (H/F) – Roumanie (Bucarest) – 12 mois renouvelables."

**I'd like to erase everything after (H/F) or (h/f) or H/F or F/H or f/h etc ...**

I tried this but not working:

```
$offer = preg_replace(array('/ F\/\H.*/','/ (F\/\H).*/','/ H\/\F.*/','/ (H\/\F).*/'), '', $offer);
```

Any idea ? Thanks a lot from France !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the pattern `\s*\(?(?:h/f|f/h)\)?.*$` and then replace with empty string:

```
$input = "V.I.E Responsable Projets Marque Propre (H/F) – Roumanie (Bucarest) – 12 mois renouvelables.";
$output = preg_replace("/\s*\(?(?:h\/f|f\/h)\)?.*$/i", "", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
V.I.E Responsable Projets Marque Propre (H/F) – Roumanie (Bucarest) – 12 mois renouvelables.
V.I.E Responsable Projets Marque Propre
```

Comment: The regular expression only works if parentheses (H/F) are present, not if they are missing h/f.

Comment: @jspit Right you are, I made the parentheses optional.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to write it, But the RegEx is mutilated in the comment.